# GLM: Get position of plane-line-intersection

Tags: c++, vector, glm-math

i am pretty new to the GLM library for C++ so I am facing some problems with it. 
I have a plane made of a position and two spanning vectors, and a line containing it's position and direction - all values are `glm::vec3`.

```
struct Plane {
  glm::vec3 position;
  glm::vec3 spanVec1;
  glm::vec3 spanVec2;
}

struct Line {
  glm::vec3 start;
  glm::vec3 direction;
}
```

Now I need the intersection point of both.
I am aware that I could find the point with a linear equation, but I would like to ensure that no INBUILD solution from glm is available, so that I don't have to write my own extension (mainly due to performance reasons).

So is there a convenient way to do this within the library? Or at least does the library contain some kind of linear equation solving?

PS: The `glm::gtx::intersect` functions are not what I am looking for, since I need the intersection point, while those only return wether or not they intersect (`boolean`).

Comment: Most functions from [`glm::gtx::intersect`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00179.html) actually give you back the intersection position, as an output parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`glm::gtx::intersect`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00203.html) doesn't have a line-plane intersection function, but it does have [`intersectRayPlane`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00203.html#ga6203e3a0822575ced2b2cd500b396b0c).

You could build a ray-plane intersection by calling that routine twice (once with `Line.direction` and once with `-line.direction`). Not the most efficient option, but perhaps suitable for many applications.

Note that `intersectRayPlane` doesn't return the intersection position directly, but the last (output) parameter is the distance along the ray to the intersection position.  So you would get the intersection position with `orig + intersectionDistance*dir`